# Trouble removing bits of texture in image

Tags: html5-canvas, tile, visual-glitch

I'm making a game in HTML5 using canvas.

When i use CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage to draw a texture that is cropped from an image you can sometimes see a small bit of the surounding textures in the image.

An example is when i render my own text from this tileset: [font "tileset"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfbei.png), where depending on the width and height of the browser window you can sometimes see glimpses of neighbouring tiles. Here you can see a bit of the letters underneath: [text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD9UT.png), and if i change the browser height by one pixel it disapears.

It seems like if the graphical glitch happens depends on the height/width of the browser window. If you change the height by 1 pixel it disapears, if you change it by one more it comes back.

Does anyone know how to fix this? And if not, should i try to like manually draw the images pixel by pixel or like add a one pixel margin to the tileset?

Comment: You answered your own question. Use a slight larger spritesheet (text image) that has a couple pixels of separation between characters.

Comment: @markE Well, i don't really want to do that if there is another way to do it, that's why i'm asking.

Comment: Shame to avoid the simplest solution, but alternatively, canvas has a half-pixel resolution so I guess you could enlarge your crop area by a half pixel and see if that omits the noise. If that doesn't work you're back to using a larger spritesheet.

Comment: @markE Oh, thanks! That worked, you should submit that as an answer!

Comment: Glad I could help...I posted both solutions in an answer. Good luck with your project!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas has a half-pixel resolution so I guess you could enlarge your crop area by a half pixel and see if that omits the noise.

If that doesn't work you're back to using a larger spritesheet.

If you decide on using a larger spritesheet, [here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/double-tileset.png) a double-sized version of your spritesheet that I Photoshopped.